# JsonObject(Java)

Tags: java, android, json

Никак не могу найти причину по которой не делается выборка из JSON, переменной userName должно присваиваться значение по ключу "status" из JsonObject.

[image: Скриншот]

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject(example.post(getUrlUser, "UserInfo"));
            JSONObject responseObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
            userName = responseObject.getString("status");
```

userName всё равно == null[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходник:

```
public class CoreActivity extends Activity {
 private String ACCESS_TOKEN = null;
 private String getUrlUser;
 private TextView txtAt;
 private TextView accesToken;
 private String userName;
 private JSONObject jsonObject;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.core_layout);

        txtAt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAt);
        accesToken = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accesToken);
        ACCESS_TOKEN = getIntent().getStringExtra("ACCESS_TOKEN");

        new ShowUserInfoAsyncTask().execute();

    }

    private class ShowUserInfoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            getUrlUser = "https://api.vk.com/method/" +
                    "account.getProfileInfo" +
                    "?" +
                    "&access_token=" +ACCESS_TOKEN+
                    "&v=5.59";

            PostExample example = new PostExample();
            try {

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(example.post(getUrlUser, "UserInfo"));
                JSONObject responseObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                userName = responseObject.getString("status");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
                accesToken.setText(userName.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: покажите пример json'а -  из скриншота не очень понятно

Comment: "response":{"first_name":"Максим","last_name":"Кульба","sex":2,"relation":2,"relation_partner":{"id":69336107,"first_name":"Алина","last_name":"Бацуева"},"relation_requests":[{"id":69336107,"first_name":"Алина","last_name":"Бацуева"}],"bdate":"12.7.1993","bdate_visibility":1,"home_town":"Макеевка","country":{"id":2,"title":"Украина"},"city":{"id":280,"title":"Харьков"},"status":"Смерть -- это только равнины.   Жизнь -- холмы.","phone":"+380 **** * ** 37"}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно сначала получить объект response:

```
JSONObject responseObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
String status = responseObject.getString("status");
```

Comment: Не помогло, всё равно status = null

Comment: @Heaven, покажите код

Comment: Добавил выше исходник

Comment: @Heaven выглядит правильно, какой Exception падает?

Comment: в том и дело, Exception не падает, просто по какой-то причине responseObject.getString("status") не возвращает ничего...может стоит использовать какую-то другую либу для работы с json?

Comment: Странно, перезагрузил телефон на котором тестировал и всё нормально заработало